# Expanding cov(cov(x,y),y) to compare to cov(x,y)

Tags: regression, variance, covariance

I am trying to compare the following two terms and determine which one is larger than the other.

Term 1: ${\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)} \over {\operatorname{var}(Y)}$

Term 2: ${\operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y), Y)} \over {(\operatorname{var}(Y))^2}$

If x and y are uncorrelated, then $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y) = 0$, so both of these terms would be $0$. What would happen if they are positively correlated? I think I'm missing some information on the properties of covariances that is preventing me from manipulating the second term.

Comment: With respect to Term 2: the covariance of $x$ and $y$ is a number, e.g., 4.25, and as such, has no covariance with anything else.

Comment: @jbowman Would that make it equal to 0?

Comment: Yes, so Term 2 is equal to 0 also.

Comment: Could you please explain the second numerator?  Assuming $X$ and $Y$ refer to random variables, then $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ is either a *fixed* number or matrix, whence its covariance with $Y$ cannot be anything other than **zero**. That strongly suggests you mean something else by your symbols, but what is it?

Comment: @whuber I meant exactly what I wrote. This was the result of a proof I'm working on. I didn't realize it would be 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Statistics like $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)$, $\operatorname{var}(X), E[X], E[Y]$ are all constants. Only when we use random variables on givens side, they become functions (*in general*) of RVs: e.g. $E[X|Y], \operatorname{var}(X|Y)$.

So, since $\operatorname{cov}(X,Y)=a$ is a constant, $\operatorname{cov}(\operatorname{cov}(X,Y), Y)=\operatorname{cov}(a,Y)=0$, which would make your second term $0$. Based on your positive/negative correlation, Term 1 is either greater or smaller than Term 2.